# Knowledge article not displaying body

Tags: knowledge, articles

I'm working on knowledge for the first time, think I set it up correctly. But when we create articles, there is a summary field but no field for the article text itself. Have been searching for hours, but can't find out what's wrong. Anyone having a clue of what I'm missing?

Comment: There's not enough information to help you out on this. Consider adding steps to reproduce what you have done and exactly what you are missing.

Comment: Check profile permissions, it could just be field level security on the field. If not please explain further where and how you are displaying the Articles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the only standard fields provided on article types are: Article Number, Summary, Title, and URL Name. If you want other fields, like a rich text area to hold some kind of information, you need to add it as a custom field to the article type. The article types are customizable objects and you need to configure them according to your individual needs.

See also: [Add Custom Fields to Article Types](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=knowledge_fields_custom_add.htm)

Comment: Thanks Paul, at first I couldn't believe it but I got it confirmed by SF support as well. It's a great product with some mysterious ways :-)

Comment: Can't believe someone downvoted this question just because he/she didn't know the answer or what?

Comment: I'm a bit lost as well, on some scratch orgs, enabling Lightning knowledge automatically creates Question__c and Answer__c fields. On others, it doesn't create anything. I can't figure out the rules...

Comment: Finally I found an interesting answer here : https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A86CmSAJ . It's going through the knowledge setup in service setup assistant that creates the fields. If service setup is not available, typing 'service setup assistant' in the setup search field helps. Hard to gues though..

Comment: I am not able to find out Article type in the setup. I have already created one custom field on Knowledge_Article__kav with a text area rich, and read permission is also given to the community guest user profile. but the content of rich text is not visible to the guest user. Any help?